What is the best way to define JSON serialization format for a class in TypeScript?
I am developing a program with Angular and TypeScript. I have a class called Signal, which has the following properties:
export class Signal {
    id: number;
    obraId: number;
    obra: string;
    descripcion: string;
    rangoInferior: string;
    rangoSuperior: string;
    unidades: string;
    // more properties

    // I use ofJson method to create a Signal object
    static ofJson(signalJson: ISignalJson): Signal {
        return this.createSignal(signalJson.id, signalJson.obraId, signalJson.obra, 
            signalJson.descripcion, signalJson.rangoInferior, signalJson.rangoSuperior,
            signalJson.unidades
        );
    }

    static createSignal(id: number, obraId: number, obra: string,descripcion: string, rangoInferior: string, rangoSuperior: string,
        unidades: string
    ): Signal {
        const new_signal = new Signal();
        new_signal.id = id;
        new_signal.obraId = obraId;
        new_signal.obra = obra;
        new_signal.descripcion = descripcion;
        new_signal.rangoInferior = rangoInferior;
        new_signal.rangoSuperior = rangoSuperior;
        new_signal.unidades = unidades;
        return new_signal;
    }
}

When I get data from an API, some fields (descripcion, rangoInferior, rangoSuperior) have null value and I want to set these to empty string. To do this, I use private properties and getters/setters.
Example:
private _descripcion: string;
public get descripcion(): string {
    return this._descripcion;
}
public set descripcion(value: string) {
    this._descripcion = value ? value : "";
}

The problem is that this object is JSON.stringifyed with underscore fields and when sent to an API will return an error.
{
  "_descripcion": "lll5",
  "id": 621284,
  "obra": "INTEGRATION-TESTS",
  "obraId": 378,
  "_rangoInferior": '',
  "_rangoSuperior": '',
  "_unidades": ''
}

I have seen several answers to solve this:

Make a toJson method and remove the underscores.
Use Object.defineProperties as below:
Object.defineProperties(
    this,
    {
        _descripcion: { 
            writable: true, 
            enumerable: false 
        },
        descripcion: {
            get() { return this._descripcion; },
            set(value: string) { this._descripcion = value ? value : ""; },
            enumerable: true
        }
    }
);


Which is the best solution?
Is there another answer which I should consider?


Okey @ChukwujiobiCanon , I appreciate your answer. Thank you. But this is not the main problem which I am searching an answer. So, If you have a solution, I will be enchanted of hearing

Okay I’ve written an actual answer.

Using toJson() will require you to always pass a reviver to JSON.parse() when parsing from JSON. This must be documented to make it easy to maintain the code.
Use Object.defineProperties() instead. it is a more verbose approach but still gives you better control over what’s going on. The ability to control which properties are writable and which are enumerable also has other advantages besides using in JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().
